# Create new module in DNN7in VSS2010

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

i have downloaded DNN7.0.6 from web and i installed it .But when i try to add new module in VS2010,it is not showing DNN module creator option when i click add item.But when i open the same project in VS2008 the option is there.Can anybody guide me how to create new dynamic module in DNN7 using VS2010[image: This is the options currently showing].Also i downloaded and installed DNN platform from http://www.dnnsoftware.com/Community/Download

Answer (score 0):

i installed new version of DNN startup from http://dotnetnuke.codeplex.com/releases/view/110757 and now working fine